# How to position an H1 on it's own heighth

Tags: html, css, layout, sass, css-position

I need some help positioning my text inside it's own height.
What I need to achieve is to attach the text to the top of the  container (as the arrow is showing). Which css property is used to do this? Why the height of the H1 is bigger that hte text itself? I made sure to apply margin and padding 0.

[image]

Comment: That space is usually **part** of the typeface and not removable. You *might* be able to reduce it by playing with the `line-height` but it's **supposed** to be there.

Comment: The idea is that there *should* be space between adjacent lines to make the text readable and no overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's supposed to be space between the top of the text and its container. It's called the line-height. A lot of that is built into the font itself.

It exists both top and bottom to account for typographic *ascenders* (top of a lower case "l" or "f" and *descenders* (bottom of a lower case "y" or "g") that extend past the baseline and x-height of the characters.

You can remove **some** of that height with CSS by adjusting `line-height`

```
h1 {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

or even negative numbers

```
h1 {
  line-height: -0.5;
}
```

Your screenshot shows what I would expect as desirable behavior where the icon and the text are aligned with each other. That said you could move the text (regardless of the actual size of element) by using negative margin or absolute positioning.

```
h1 {
 margin-top: -5px;
 /* moves the text up 5 px */
}

h1 {
 /* takes the h1 out of the normal flow */
 position: absolute;
 top: -5px;
}
```